# Setting identity for a gitlab user with rest api

Tags: python, rest, api, python-requests, gitlab

I'm also posting my question here. Maybe anyone has a pragmatic way to solve this:

Currently I've been messing around with automatically creating users in gitlab-ce, adding existing ssh-keys to them and afterwards, changing their identity to a different provider, in my case atlassian crowd. I tried to set it when doing a post request on user creation by adding `{ 'identities': [ { 'provider': 'crowd', 'external_uid': 'foobar' } ] }` into my request, but while the user is correctly created, the identity setting gets ignored. The request actually looks like the following and is sent against http://localhost/api/v3/users

```
{
  "email": "foo.bar@aol.com",
  "password": "aol123aol123",
  "username": "foo.bar",
  "name": "Foo Bar",
  "identities": [
    {
      "provider": "crowd",
      "extern_uid": "fbar"
    }
  ]
}
```

As I said, the user is created, but not the identity. Directly setting the identity through API, that is, setting a certain identity provide along with an id at the external system, seems not to be implemented. That's why I filed an issue at gitlab.com (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27693).

I'm looking now for an alternative to fix this. I'm working on a migration from different technologies and I want to automate the usermanagement first. As there a couple of them, it's not feasible to do this manually.

As a matter of fact, it is possible to set the identity of a user in the admin ui. Inspecting it through the browser when clicking on the create button showed, that it is a POST request against

http://localhost/admin/users/foo.bar/identities

the content is url-encoded:

```
utf8:✓
authenticity_token:47yRB038sLQQ7bBP4vYGdVcQzg/8js09h5mUkz5vNYSALAjRqIpAFjYube8VxUlEKChNcrjNmx7s0RW8tDWFqC==
identity[provider]:crowd
identity[extern_uid]:fbar
```

As you can see, it's not an API url, but the ui. What is unknown to me here is the authenticity_token. It's not the private access token of the admin. Is it a session token?

From a technology point I'm using python w/ requests to do all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you need [sudo](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#sudo) support offered by gitlab-ce's API.